# How to make OnDelete CASCADE work using Hibernate Inheritance models

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Parent :

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "Parent")  
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Parent {
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)  
    @Column(name = "id")  
    protected int id;  
    //some code here
}
```

Child1 :

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="Child1")   
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
public class Child1 extends Parent {
        //some code here
}
```

I'm making tables in MySQL using Hibernate Mapping.
I'm absolutely new to Hibernate. Tables are getting created and also Child Table has a foreign key that references the Parent table id as I have mentioned the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation.
Adding a field in the child table also adds it to the Parent table as it's been extended.
But deleting a row in parent table does not delete the child table rows.
Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach here somewhere. 
My end goal is to extend the parent, and add records to it using the child table.
I need some pointers. Maybe other annotations, some other way to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding ***`ON DELETE CASCADE`*** to the foreign key of the child table.

Refer : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT,
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```